# Update static file references with a version

Tags: regex, ant

In our web application we have lots of JS and CSS files.
We need to append a version number to these references every time we deploy the code. This is to make sure that users always get the latest deployed version of the file, and the file will not be served from browser's cache. We plan to do this using our build script.
We need to append a parameter to the file reference like `<script type="text/javascript src=./abc/test.js?v=1231`/>.

We need to do this for all CSS and JS files.
Can someone please suggest the best appraoch to do this?

We are planning to do this using regular expression. We will append a random number to the file name.

Can you please help me how I can find out all the CSS and JS reference in my HTML page?

Comment: Write a custom ant task in which you can play with Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you need to find all the CSS and javascript references in your HTML files? It would be simpler to use a replaceable token in these files and then run a task in ant to do the replacements. Ant only needs to find the tokens.

You could do this with the [ReplaceRegExp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html) task (to make the substitution in place), or you could do a Copy or Move with a [FilterSet](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterset.html) (to make the substitution in copies of the target files).

Here is an example using ReplaceRegExp:

```
<project default="test">

  <property name="build.version" value="1231"/>

  <target name="test">
    <replaceregexp match="\@BUILD_VERSION\@" replace="${build.version}">
      <fileset dir="test">
        <include name="*.html"/>
      </fileset>
    </replaceregexp>
  </target>

</project>
```

Here is a sample file before running the build:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./abc/test.js?v=@BUILD_VERSION@"/>
  </head>
</html>
```

And here it is after:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./abc/test.js?v=1231"/>
  </head>
</html>
```